# How to do this Viewbox responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, viewbox

This paralax web is do with SVG's. The problem is when i want to do this responsive. In mobile the images are too small, so I want to zoom it only in movile format. I try to change viewbox numbers, but when I change that, changes in all formats. How can I do? I'm so noob in that.

Thank you so much for help.

```js
gsap.set('.main', {position:'fixed', background:'#fff', width:'100%', maxWidth:'1200px', height:'100%', top:0, left:'50%', x:'-50%'})
gsap.set('.scrollDist', {width:'100%', height:'200%'})
gsap.timeline({scrollTrigger:{trigger:'.scrollDist', start:'top top', end:'bottom bottom', scrub:1}})
    .fromTo('.sky', {y:0},{y:-200}, 0)
    .fromTo('.cloud1', {y:100},{y:-800}, 0)
    .fromTo('.cloud2', {y:-150},{y:-500}, 0)
    .fromTo('.cloud3', {y:-50},{y:-650}, 0)
    .fromTo('.mountBg', {y:-10},{y:-100}, 0)
    .fromTo('.mountMg', {y:-30},{y:-250}, 0)
    .fromTo('.mountFg', {y:-50},{y:-600}, 0)

$('#arrowBtn').on('mouseenter', (e)=>{ gsap.to('.arrow', {y:10, duration:0.8, ease:'back.inOut(3)', overwrite:'auto'}); })
$('#arrowBtn').on('mouseleave', (e)=>{ gsap.to('.arrow', {y:0, duration:0.5, ease:'power3.out', overwrite:'auto'}); })
$('#arrowBtn').on('click', (e)=>{ gsap.to(window, {scrollTo:innerHeight, duration:1.5, ease:'power1.inOut'}); }) // scrollTo requires the ScrollTo plugin (not to be confused w/ ScrollTrigger)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap');

body, html {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#ddd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size:99px;
  text-align:center;
}

div {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - ScrollTrigger: SVG Text Mask</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<!-- This is a recreation of Unfold's (https://dribbble.com/unfold) parallax scene: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/14268/screenshots/3275340/northface.gif -->
<div class="scrollDist"></div>
<div class="main">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1200 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <mask id="m">
      <g class="cloud1">
        <rect fill="#fff" width="100%" height="801" y="799" />
        <image xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/cloud1Mask.jpg" width="1200" height="800"/>
      </g>
    </mask>
    
    <image class="sky" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/sky.jpg"  width="1200" height="590" />
    <image class="mountBg" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/mountBg.png" width="1200" height="800"/>    
    <image class="mountMg" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/mountMg.png" width="1200" height="800"/>    
    <image class="cloud2" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/cloud2.png" width="1200" height="800"/>    
    <image class="mountFg" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/mountFg.png" width="1200" height="800"/>
    <image class="cloud1" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/cloud1.png" width="1200" height="800"/>
    <image class="cloud3" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/cloud3.png" width="1200" height="800"/>
    <text fill="#fff" x="350" y="200">EXPLORE</text>
    <polyline class="arrow" fill="#fff" points="599,250 599,289 590,279 590,282 600,292 610,282 610,279 601,289 601,250" />
    
    <g mask="url(#m)">
      <rect fill="#fff" width="100%" height="100%" />      
      <text x="350" y="200" fill="#162a43">FURTHER</text>
    </g>
    
    <rect id="arrowBtn" width="100" height="100" opacity="0" x="550" y="220" style="cursor:pointer"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollToPlugin.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow, I had to grab a copy of this effect, its epic.

Comment: Thanks... but it don't help me